# Undo Within Selection?

Tags: visual-studio, text-editor, undo

Is there a way to get an "Undo within Selection" feature in Visual Studio?  If not, are there any editors that have this functionality?

It just seems exceptionally useful, removing the need to undo x many times, copy, redo x many times and paste.  Instead one could just highlight the region of interest and undo in that location...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like there's no way to do this presently in Visual Studio. [It](http://www.charlesrcook.com/archive/2009/06/07/undo-within-selected.aspx) [has been](http://lists.kde.org/?l=kwrite-devel&m=111237531620005&w=2) [suggested](http://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=103021) in a few places, though. So who knows, maybe Microsoft will take the lead in developing this feature.

Sadly, it doesn't look like anyone tried to implement this feature in their text editor, but you could earn some serious cred by developing it before anyone else!

Comment: Thank you Jweede for looking into it.  Though very useful, I'm sure the devil is in the details of implementing that...  Perhaps I will give it a go the next time I am looking for a 'fun' project.